# PDF metadata in file explorer column

Tags: pdf

Many pdf files such as datasheets or application notes are files named ANxxx with an explicit title such as "Cortex M3 ...". In file explorer, you can rename it with PDF doc name in order to find it easily but it's not very convenient.

Some times ago, I got a windows machine, I could add a category in file explorer that displayed PDF name.

Are some linux file explorer able to show a PDF title category when detailed view is selected? I would like to have PDF document name extracted from pdf metadata  in a dedicated column.

I'm using thunar.

Comment: Gnome `tracker` was designed with this use case in mind... [Gnome Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/WhatIsTracker)

Comment: Nice project, but I think my need is a little bit different. My first goal is to have pdf name displayed in a file manager window column

Comment: Gnome `nautilus` uses `tracker` ... If you are looking for a **heavy** file manager, `nautilus` has lots of extras which can be added on to perform pretty much what you are looking for... like [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NautilusSidebarExtensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RuberStamp pointed out, Nautilus is very extensible. I'm now using it. I managed to show PDF title in detailed column view using python bindings. 
You will find details [here](https://gist.github.com/Lahorde/4cde873e72249c58f1ccd3d22bcb8a85)